# MstarUpgrade.bin file unpack

Tags: python, android-tv, bin, unpack

i want to unpack a MstarUpgrade.bin file

device detail: philips tv,model: 49PUT7032/56 , android version: 5.1.8
,searching and find [this](https://github.com/dipcore/mstar-bin-tool)

do steps but got error:

```
       [i] Analizing header ...
       [i] Saving header script
       [i] Parsing script ...
       .
       .
       .
       if env[key]:
       KeyError: 'UpgradeImage'
```

any solutions...? or any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I remember using this in the past. Under Ubuntu 18, the script complained about something (which could be this or else), but under Windows 10, the bin file decompressed fine to all the required image files.